# Cant get scroll bar to appear when the itemsource template is populated

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I spent a long time try to figure out how to get the scroll bar to work with a list of data:

```
  <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,6,0,0"  >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBox Width="Auto" Margin="18,0,0,0"
                                     Text="{Binding ItemsProp1}" 
                                     IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.Column="1" 
                                      IsReadOnly="True" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsProp2}" 
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding ItemsProp3}" Margin="6,0,0,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
```

I've seen examples with using an ItemTemplate instead of DataTemplate, so I'm not even sure if it possible with DataTemplate.

I've tried adding a scrollviewer to the grid and that didn't work either.I've also tried defining a scrollviewer above the ItemsControl element. When the scroll appears, it still doesn't actually scroll.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding a `ScrollViewer` to the `Grid` in your template then you're adding it to *each individual item*, not to the list as a whole.

The easiest solution is to wrap the list itself in a `ScrollViewer`:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl>
       .....
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I mentioned I tried doing that as well, but the scroll bar doesn't work.. I wonder if it has to do with the height of the grid

Comment: By doesn't work, I mean the scrollviewer is visible, my data goes off the screen and I cant actually scroll.

Comment: I needed to set the max height of the scrollviewer -_-